# Unable to target salt minion using customized grains

Tags: salt-stack

I created a simple SaltStack Cluster with a master and minion. Then I manually added a customized grains to the minion in the file `/etc/salt/grains`.

```
mykey: hello-key
```

I did see this key when running `salt '*' grains.items` in the master

```
...
localhost:
      ip-172-31-24-109.us-west-2.compute.internal
  lsb_distrib_codename:
      CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
  lsb_distrib_id:
      CentOS Linux
  machine_id:
      b30d0f2110ac3807b210c19ede3ce88f
  manufacturer:
      Xen
  master:
      ec2-54-186-104-181.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  mdadm:
  mem_total:
      15883
  mykey:
      hello-key
  ...
```

Now the weird part is when I tried to target this minion through my customized grains, it doesn't work while every other way works!

```
[root@ip-172-31-28-130 ~]# salt '*' saltutil.refresh_modules
ip-172-31-24-109.us-west-2.compute.internal:
    True
[root@ip-172-31-28-130 ~]# salt '*' test.ping
ip-172-31-24-109.us-west-2.compute.internal:
    True
[root@ip-172-31-28-130 ~]# salt -G 'mem_total:*' test.ping
ip-172-31-24-109.us-west-2.compute.internal:
    True

[root@ip-172-31-28-130 ~]# salt -G 'mykey:hello-key' test.ping
ip-172-31-24-109.us-west-2.compute.internal:
    Minion did not return. [No response]
```

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Basically every time I added a new grain key-value, it seems I must restart the minion machine to get it work. It is reproduced every time pretty much. Just follow that tutorial, get two VMs on AWS, one master one minion, add a new grain key value on the minon, then run salt -G 'newkey:newvalue' test.ping. It never works for me (I tried all kinds of refresh) unless I restart the minion machine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you really have a connectivity problem, not a targetting one.
Your targetting is OK, if it was not you would have a message like

```
$ salt 'minion' test.ping
No minions matched the target. No command was sent, no jid was assigned.
ERROR: No return received
```

Comment: Thanks @daks it seems I must restart the minion machine to get it work.

Comment: I don't think it is a connectivity problem. As you can see, if I use '*' or any old grains, the minion respond correctly. But whenever I added a new grain, and tried to target the minion with the new grain key-value, then "No return received". I think it is kind of a bug in the saltstack

Comment: your previous comment let me think it was solved to you